# AngularJS ngRepeat within Directiving using a locally defined collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to figure out how to use a locally defined array of objects within a directive for use of an ngRepeat - I'm not using any controllers for these.

I've got a directive template setup like below

```
<div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group env-switcher">
        <a
            ng-repeat="env in environments" ng-click="setEnv(env)" ng-class="{'active': env.active}"
            href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" >

            <i class="fa {{env.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;{{env.label}}

        </a>
    </div>
```

and I've got my directive code

```
App.directive('envSwitcher', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs){

            $scope.activeEnvironment = 'unknown';

            $scope.environments = [
                {
                    label: 'Local',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-down',
                    value: 'local',
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Staging',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-rock-o',
                    value: 'staging',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Live',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-up',
                    value: 'live',
                    active: false
                }
            ];

            $scope.setEnv = function(env){

                angular.forEach($scope.environments, function(model, key){

                    if( angular.equals(env, model) ){
                        model.active = true;
                        $scope.activeEnvironment = model.value;
                    }
                    else {
                        model.active = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

However, when you have multiple of these on the page, the $scope bleeds out and updates them all. So if I run the `setEnv` function on `Directive Instance 1` then `Directive Instance 2 and 3` also change.

I'm aware there is a `scope` property which i've tried to set to `scope: {}` to isolate it, however then the ngRepeat doesn't show anything - im guessing because I've done something wrong.

How would I achieve the above? e.g Using a locally defined array of object, to use with ngRepeat within the directives template, without the $scope bleed?

Thanks

Comment: You're reusing parent scope, try add isolated scope with `scope: {}`

Comment: I've already mentioned in the question that i've tried with an isolated scope, but that then stops the ngRepeat from displaying anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the current behaviour that you want to avoid:

```js
function envSwitcher() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs){

            $scope.activeEnvironment = 'unknown';

            $scope.environments = [
                {
                    label: 'Local',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-down',
                    value: 'local',
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Staging',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-rock-o',
                    value: 'staging',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Live',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-up',
                    value: 'live',
                    active: false
                }
            ];

            $scope.setEnv = function(env){
                angular.forEach($scope.environments, function(model, key){

                    if( angular.equals(env, model) ){
                        model.active = true;
                        $scope.activeEnvironment = model.value;
                    }
                    else {
                        model.active = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('envSwitcher', envSwitcher);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group env-switcher">
        <a ng-repeat="env in environments"
          ng-click="setEnv(env)"
          ng-class="{'active': env.active}"
          href=""
          class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            {{env.label}}
        </a> <span>Active env: {{activeEnvironment}}</span>
  </div>
  <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group env-switcher">
        <a ng-repeat="env in environments"
          ng-click="setEnv(env)"
          ng-class="{'active': env.active}"
          href=""
          class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            {{env.label}}
        </a> <span>Active env: {{activeEnvironment}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You share a scope between your directives. If you want them to be independent, you have to put the `a link` inside a template of your directive which will allow isolating the scope.

Here I use a component-like directive using `controller` instead of `link` because an independent, statefull directive should be a component. (and I don't know which angular version you are using or if directives are imposed on you)

I also restricted the directive to attribute because using class directives is not best practice.

```js
function envSwitcher() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    template: `
      <a ng-repeat="env in ec.environments"
        ng-click="ec.setEnv(env)"
        ng-class="{'active': env.active}"
        href=""
        class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
          {{env.label}}
      </a> <span>Active env: {{ec.activeEnvironment}}</span>
    `,
    controller: envController,
    controllerAs: 'ec'
  }
}

function envController() {
  var vm = this;
  this.activeEnvironment = 'unknown';
  this.setEnv = setEnv;
  this.environments = [
    {
      label: 'Local',
      icon: 'fa-hand-o-down',
      value: 'local',
      active: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Staging',
      icon: 'fa-hand-rock-o',
      value: 'staging',
      active: false
    },
    {
      label: 'Live',
      icon: 'fa-hand-o-up',
      value: 'live',
      active: false
    }
  ];

  function setEnv(env){
    angular.forEach(vm.environments, function(model, key){
      if(angular.equals(env, model)){
        model.active = true;
        vm.activeEnvironment = model.value;
      }
      else {
        model.active = false;
      }
    });
  }
}

    angular.module('myApp', []);
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('envSwitcher', envSwitcher)
        .controller('envController', envController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="radioBtn" env-switcher class="btn-group"></div>
  <div id="radioBtn" env-switcher class="btn-group"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

To make your original code work with minimal changes, you have to copy the content of the div (a href...) in the template of the directive and then you can add the isolate scope.

```js
function envSwitcher() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {},
        template: `
        <a ng-repeat="env in environments"
          ng-click="setEnv(env)"
          ng-class="{'active': env.active}"
          href=""
          class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            {{env.label}}
        </a> <span>Active env: {{activeEnvironment}}</span>
`,
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs){

            $scope.activeEnvironment = 'unknown';

            $scope.environments = [
                {
                    label: 'Local',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-down',
                    value: 'local',
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Staging',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-rock-o',
                    value: 'staging',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'Live',
                    icon: 'fa-hand-o-up',
                    value: 'live',
                    active: false
                }
            ];

            $scope.setEnv = function(env){
                angular.forEach($scope.environments, function(model, key){

                    if( angular.equals(env, model) ){
                        model.active = true;
                        $scope.activeEnvironment = model.value;
                    }
                    else {
                        model.active = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('envSwitcher', envSwitcher);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group env-switcher"></div>
  <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group env-switcher"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this - just to understand, is there are reasons you could not use the html in the template itself? and must we setup a controller somewhere for it to work? as I could just instead of using a directive use a controller for the whole thing then the issue wouldnt happen anyway?

Comment: @OwenMelbourne this is something I have to try before answering. It's possible that you need an ng-transclude to use the isolate scope. If I manage to make your original code work with minimum changes I will update the question.

Comment: @OwenMelbourne answer edited. This is the best I can do with the original code :)

Comment: nah thats cool, any idea why the template needs to be embedded into the directive?

Comment: @OwenMelbourne because outside of the directive it doesn't have access to the isolated scope of the directive :)